# Invsible objects

Tags: objects, transparency

I just installed Blender 2.81. When I first started it, I saw the orange outline of the selected cube, but not the cube itself. The objects show up in edit mode, but disappear when I return to object mode.Also, if I render the image,I just get a cut out in the background in the shape of the missing image. Has anyone else ran into this problem with the new blender 2.81?

Comment: Is there any thing present in the outliner panel?

Comment: Yeah, the objects are in the outliner.

Comment: So the cube might been **hide from viewport**. Try `atl+h` to unhide every thing. Also to check hidden icon in outliner for detail: [outliner option](/questions/144959/2-8-locking-object-from-selection/144961#144961)